# how to import less css file into html head

Tags: html, css, less

I have a `CSS LESS` file, and it include css less code. I am trying to import it into my html file, in the `head`, like so:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
</head>
```

However, the css is not processing, and there is no css showing up all just non-css stuff on the html page.

am i importing it wrong?

Comment: What's in your script.js file? You have to tell less.js what to process.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's in you less.js file, but in case less.js is a script to compile your less file, you have to put it before the link tag in your head.

```
<head>
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
</head>
```